# Installing Discovery on Server with Information Server

Tags: ibm-information-server

I am trying to install Discovery on the same server as IIS which already has a DB2 instance. As the Discovery installation guide says, to install with an existing DB2 instance the repository database must be manually configured. It then goes on to say that this can be done using scripts which are found under the install directory. In other words, before I install I have to use something only available after installation.

Has anyone got a workaround - a link to somewhere I can get the scripts perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by installing onto a clean VM and then copying the scripts from the installation folder and other files referenced in the scripts onto the IIS server and running from there. Had to search and replace the DB2 install directory within the scripts as they expect a default install of :\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB whereas the IIS default install of DB2 is to \IBM\SQLLIB.